# c# do if statments break loops

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach, nested, break

Datasources:  Datatable with employee information

I'm trying to group my data by employee name,  then output the employee name and below that output the records associated with that employee and only that employee.

I've got an if statement within a nested for each which is within another for each (I also tried regular for loops) .  The if statement checks the employee name against the current name it's iterating with and outputs the record's information if it is true.  This works great for the first record of each employee.  After the first iteration per employee it breaks and process of elimination has shown me that it's because of the if statement.  It's like using an if statement breaks the loop.

---

```
public String GroupAndSortTableData(DataTable thisDataTable)
    {
        //detailActivitiesDataTable datatable column key
        //0 = currentID, 1 = formerID, 2 = Description, 3 = MonthID, 4 = Year, 5 = CreatedBy, 6 = CreatedOn, 7 = ModifiedBy, 
        //8 = ModifiedOn, 9 = UserID, 10 = Signed, 11 = Type, 12 = Software, 13 = Activity, 14 = DeleteFlag, 15 = DeletedBy, 16 = DeletedOn
        //17 = UserName, 18 = SortName, 19 = FullName
        try
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder strReport = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            //get unique values in the SortName column of detailActivitiesDataTable
                         group row by row.Field<string>("SortName") into grp
                         select new
                         {
                             SortName = grp.Key,
                             //MemberCount = grp.Count()
                         };
            strReport.AppendLine("<table width='800px' class='light' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr><th align='left' colspan='4'> A C T I V I T I E S</th></tr></table>");
            strReport.AppendLine("<table width='800px' class='light' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr><th align='left' colspan='4'><hr></th></tr></table>");
            //display a subheader bar for each name in the data
            foreach (var uniqueName in result)
            {
                //testing messagebow works in localhost only    
                strReport.AppendLine("<table class='dark' width='800px'><tr><th colspan='4' align='left'>" + uniqueName.SortName + "</th></tr>");
                strStaffActivities.AppendLine("<tr><td colspan='4' align='left'><hr width='800px'></td></tr>");
                strReport.AppendLine("<tr>"
                                                + "<td class='lightHeader2' width='150'>Type</td>"
                                                + "<td class='lightHeader2' width='150'>Activity</td>"
                                                + "<td class='lightHeader2' width='150'>Software</td>"
                                                + "<td class='lightHeader2' width='350'>Description</td>"
                                                + "</tr></table>");
                strReport.AppendLine("<table class='light' width='800px'>");
                //loop through the rows of the datatable 
                foreach(DataRow dtRow in thisDataTable.Rows)
                {
                    //if it matches the username display the content
                    if (dtRow[18] == uniqueName.SortName)
                    {
                        strReport.AppendLine("<tr>");
                        strReport.AppendLine("<td class='light' width='150'>" + dtRow[11] + "</td>");
                        strReport.AppendLine("<td class='light' width='150'>" + dtRow[13] + "</td>");
                        strReport.AppendLine("<td class='light' width='150'>" + dtRow[12] + "</td>");
                        strReport.AppendLine("<td class='light' width='350'>" + dtRow[2] + "</td>");
                        strReport.AppendLine("<td class='light' width='350'>" + dtRow[18] + "</td>");
                        strReport.AppendLine("<td class='light' width='350'>" + uniqueName.SortName + "</td>");
                        strReport.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }

            }
            strReport.AppendLine("</table>");
            return strReport.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception eGroupActivitiesDetail)
        {
            var resultException = MessageBox.Show("Exception occurred while grouping and sorting data." + eGroupActivitiesDetail);
            return "failure";
        }
    }
```

Comment: If an exception is not being thrown, which would result in the message box being shown, then it is merely that the `if` condition is only true sometimes and not always when expected - or perhaps the loop simply had no more items to iterate. There is no "issue" with either `if-loop` interaction here, excepting as how they may be used. Attach the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Also, for sake of sanity, I suggest using a report or template engine/library if such code is duplicated.

Comment: Yes it must be that the if condition is only true sometimes, but when removing the If and adding the dtRow[18] to the output I can see that it should result in a true.  That was what made me consider the idea that an if statement resulting in false could end a loop.  But I can't find any information to confirm that.

Comment: An if condition that resolves to `false` will not cause a loop to terminate unless there is a `break` or statement executed as a result of that evaluation. Your `if` statement isn't the cause of your problem here. If eyeball inspection says that the condition should evaluate to `true`, but it doesn't, then likely there are non-printing characters in one of the values. Check their lengths. If the lengths are the same, write code to check them character-by-character and see where the difference is. Often, two non-equal characters can look very similar.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  Good suggestion.  I don't think that's the issue though because the data that I am comparing to and from come from the same source.  So if there is a nonprinting character in one of the variables of the If expression it would be in the other as well.

Answer (score 2):

An `if` statement can "break the loop" if its condition contains an instruction that triggers an exception.

Your `if (dtRow[18] == uniqueName.SortName)` is a good suspect for producing an "index out of bounds" exception in case `dtRow` does not have the element at index 18. You should add a check to see if the index is valid before referencing it to avoid throwing an exception.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion.  It may be an index out of bounds but I'm not getting that as an exception through the catch.  I've also tried this without the if statement and it works, but gives me all records for every employee.  But yes, I've checked the index and it does have data and is the desired field.  Is it possible for there to be an exception without it being caught by the catch?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, there was bad data in the datatable.